# How do I monitor which file changes during changing settings?

Tags: monitoring

I want to monitor file/files changes during the changing any settings. I can monitor changes by using `dconf watch /` but this command just monitoring path for settings and I want its file not schema path. Is there any tool/command to monitor file changes?

I only want `/path/to/filename` from result of monitoring.

For example I want to know which file changes after changing my brightness setting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the command line tool `inotifywatch` from the package `inotify-tools`.

If you want to monitor all files in you home directory for change, use this command:

```
inotifywatch -r $HOME
```

Probably the command will raise an error because the upper limit of watches is reached. You can change those with

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 16384 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches'
```

(adjust the number accordingly)