# How to record all modifications to directories, subdirectories and files in one session?

Tags: command-line, files, session, history

How can I record all the modifications to directories, subdirectories and files made during one session (ie. during login time)?

For example, listing all the files/folders that were modified, and placing that information into a text file.

I have no idea how to do this, so even a little guidance would be useful...

Comment: Do you want the modifications to persist? If not: http://askubuntu.com/a/548712/158442 What does Python have to do with this?

Comment: @muru yes I do - wouldn't a script be needed?

Comment: `inotify` can tell you what changed, but not how it changed, and only with some limited recursion (though a large limit, I think): http://askubuntu.com/questions/543960/how-do-i-monitor-which-file-changes-during-changing-settings, http://askubuntu.com/a/541144/158442, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699293/how-to-monitor-a-complete-directory-tree-for-changes-in-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inotifywatch` to collect statistics and redirect the output.

```
$ inotifywatch -r $HOME > /path/to/log
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch

Or use `inotifywait` to get a change-by-change, file-by-file update.

```
$ inotifywait -mr $HOME > /path/to/log
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait