# How to check who opened files on UBUNTU 18.4

Tags: 18.04, security, hacking

I use Ubuntu 18.04

Today, I left the computer on and no one used it. And when I came back home, I saw a lot of directories, files, and images opened.

I wonder if anyone hacked into my computer?

Comment: You can use [inotifywatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711038/how-to-record-all-modifications-to-directories-subdirectories-and-files-in-one/711047#711047)

Comment: you can to some degree find what happened and when by looking at the system logs.

Comment: @Goku You should also take note of the fact that some moving thing might have walked on your keyboard, e.g a certain "Tom" or "Jerry"... :)

Comment: Maybe I left my headphones on keyboard, I can't remember. If its true, How a few keyboard buttons can open directories, files...?

Answer (score 1):

The information you're looking for isn't there.

As you saw it open, the files was opened by your user account. There is no logging of which physical person used the computer - except for the user account logs.

Furthermore, if anyone hacked into your computer, it's highly unlikely that they would open files in this manner. Do you have for instance a cat that may have had a walk on the keyboard?

Comment: my cat turn my laptop on and creates a lot of crazy stuff from time to time so this is not an unlikely explanation of what happened,if the op has a cat that is.

Comment: Thanks for response, Maybe I left my headphones on keyboard, I can't remember. If its true, How a few keyboard buttons can open directories, files...?

If I understand you, every attack open a new window which I can't see